# Formatting buttons in a form (CodeIgniter)

Tags: css, codeigniter

Just wondering how to go about giving a form in CodeIgniter a class? I've tried just formatting buttons, hoping that the submit button would change in the form, but it didn't.

```
echo form_open('User/feed' class='buttonClass');
echo form_submit('NF', 'News Feed');            
echo form_close();
```

I couldn't find anything which seemed to help me online.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo form_open('User/feed', array( 'class' => 'classname' ));
// will become:
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/User/feed" class="classname" />


echo form_submit('NF', 'News Feed'); 
// will become:
<input type="submit" name="NF" value="News Feed" />


echo form_close();
// will become:
</form></div></div>
```

Now keep in mind, adding classes and other attributes via the array in the first line up there only adds them to the Form line. I would recomend, if you're doing this in view, writing pure html and adding in the information needed. More like:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="<?= base_url('User/feed'); ?>" class="classname">
    <div>
        Something here for the form
        <input type="text" name="stuff" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="NF" value="News Feed" class="myButton" />
</form>
```

Also,  of note, you can create buttons using an array and assign class and other attributes that way. Such as:

```
$myButton = array(
    'class' => 'myButton',
    'name' => 'NF',
    'value' => 'News Feed',
);
echo form_button($myButton);
```

Lastly, and I think this is what you're aiming for, you can do the same with `form_submit`:

```
$myButton = array(
    'class' => 'mySubmitButton',
    'name' => 'nfSubmit',
    'value' => 'Submit',
);
echo form_submit($data);
```

Comment: Not a problem. Always glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, the form helper accepts an array as the second parameter, allowing one to apply various options, such as a class. For example:

```
$attributes = array(
     'class'=>'myClass'
);
echo form_open('User/feed', $attributes);
```

**Documentation**

- Form Helper - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html